# Ionic 1 : only able to slide page from 1 to 5 but not more

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to have slide tab for 7 pages, but it works correctly from page 1 to page 5 ,but page 6 and page 7 will repeat page 1 and 2.

I am not sure which part is incorrect. Took out any of the two pages will work correctly.

**Template**

```
<ion-content id="screenerContent" scroll="false">
      <div class="row slideTabWrapper">
      <div class="col col-30 one" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==0}" ng-click="currentSlide = 0">Top Technical</div>
      <div class="col col-30 two" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==1}" ng-click="currentSlide = 1">Bottom Technical</div>
      <div class="col col-30 three" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==2}" ng-click="currentSlide = 2">Top Fundamental</div>
      <div class="col col-30 four" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==3}" ng-click="currentSlide = 3">Bottom Fundamental</div>
      <div class="col col-30 five" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==4}" ng-click="currentSlide = 4">Top Overall</div>
      <div class="col col-30 six" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==5}" ng-click="currentSlide = 5">Bottom Overall</div> 
      <div class="col col-30 seven" ng-class="{selected: currentSlide==6}" ng-click="currentSlide = 6">Market Stats</div>
    </div>

    <ion-slide-box class="slider" show-pager="false" active-slide="currentSlide">
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item row" ng-repeat="bStock in topBuy" ng-click="openDetail(bStock)">
            <div class="col col-30 stockCol">
              <p>{{bStock.Stock}}</p>
              <p>{{bStock.Name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col boldText vindexCol" ng-class="colorCoding[bStock.Trade]"><span>T: {{bStock.Tindex | number:2}}</span></div>
            <div class="col previousCol"><span>{{bStock.Previous_close}}</span></div>
            <div class="col changeCol" ng-class="{red: bStock.Change<0, green: bStock.Change>0,orange: bStock.Change==0}">
              <p>{{bStock.Change}}</p>
              <p>({{(bStock.Change_pc>=0)?"+":""}}{{bStock.Change_pc}}%)</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>

      <ion-slide>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item row" ng-repeat="sStock in topSell"  ng-click="openDetail(sStock)" >
            <div class="col col-30 stockCol">
              <p>{{sStock.Stock}}</p>
              <p>{{sStock.Name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col boldText vindexCol" ng-class="colorCoding[sStock.Trade]"><span>T: {{sStock.Tindex | number:2}}</span></div>
            <div class="col previousCol"><span>{{sStock.Previous_close}}</span></div>
            <div class="col changeCol" ng-class="{red: sStock.Change<0, green: sStock.Change>0,orange: sStock.Change==0}">
              <p>{{sStock.Change}}</p>
              <p>({{(sStock.Change_pc>=0)?"+":""}}{{sStock.Change_pc}}%)</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item row" ng-repeat="aStock in topFin" ng-click="openDetail(aStock)">
              <div class="col col-30 stockCol">
                <p>{{aStock.Stock}}</p>
                <p>{{aStock.Name}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col boldText vindexCol" ng-class="colorCoding[aStock.Trade]"><span>F: {{aStock.Findex | number:2}}</span></div>
              <div class="col previousCol"><span>{{aStock.Previous_close}}</span></div>
              <div class="col changeCol" ng-class="{red: aStock.Change<0, green: aStock.Change>0,orange: aStock.Change==0}">
                <p>{{aStock.Change}}</p>
                <p>({{(aStock.Change_pc>=0)?"+":""}}{{aStock.Change_pc}}%)</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item row" ng-repeat="cStock in bottomFin"  ng-click="openDetail(cStock)" >
              <div class="col col-30 stockCol">
                <p>{{cStock.Stock}}</p>
                <p>{{cStock.Name}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col boldText vindexCol" ng-class="colorCoding[cStock.Trade]"><span>F: {{cStock.Findex | number:2}}</span></div>
              <div class="col previousCol"><span>{{cStock.Previous_close}}</span></div>
              <div class="col changeCol" ng-class="{red: cStock.Change<0, green: cStock.Change>0,orange: cStock.Change==0}">
                <p>{{cStock.Change}}</p>
                <p>({{(cStock.Change_pc>=0)?"+":""}}{{cStock.Change_pc}}%)</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item row" ng-repeat="dStock in topVin" ng-click="openDetail(dStock)">
              <div class="col col-30 stockCol">
                <p>{{dStock.Stock}}</p>
                <p>{{dStock.Name}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col boldText vindexCol" ng-class="colorCoding[dStock.Trade]"><span>V: {{dStock.Vindex | number:2}}</span></div>
              <div class="col previousCol"><span>{{dStock.Previous_close}}</span></div>
              <div class="col changeCol" ng-class="{red: dStock.Change<0, green: dStock.Change>0,orange: dStock.Change==0}">
                <p>{{dStock.Change}}</p>
                <p>({{(dStock.Change_pc>=0)?"+":""}}{{dStock.Change_pc}}%)</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item row" ng-repeat="eStock in bottomVin"  ng-click="openDetail(eStock)" >
              <div class="col col-30 stockCol">
                <p>{{eStock.Stock}}</p>
                <p>{{eStock.Name}}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col boldText vindexCol" ng-class="colorCoding[eStock.Trade]"><span>V: {{eStock.Vindex | number:2}}</span></div>
              <div class="col previousCol"><span>{{eStock.Previous_close}}</span></div>
              <div class="col changeCol" ng-class="{red: eStock.Change<0, green: eStock.Change>0,orange: eStock.Change==0}">
                <p>{{eStock.Change}}</p>
                <p>({{(eStock.Change_pc>=0)?"+":""}}{{eStock.Change_pc}}%)</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col boldText" ng-class="colorCoding[marketSentiment]">
            Market Sentiment: {{marketSentiment}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col boldText">

            <div class="barChart">
              <div class="green" style="width: {{bar.green/bar.total *100}}%;"></div><div class="orange" style="width: {{bar.orange/bar.total *100}}%;"></div><div class="red" style="width: {{bar.red/bar.total *100}}%;"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="greenText">Bull: {{bar.green}}</span><br>
            <span class="orangeText">Neutral: {{bar.orange}}</span><br>
            <span class="redText">Bear: {{bar.red}}</span><br>

          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
```

**angular.js**

```
angular.module('myproject.controllers').controller('stockScreenerCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cashDataFactory', '$webServicesFactory', '$marketProvider', '$colorCodeProvider', '$state', '$globalFactory', '$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $cashDataFactory, $webServicesFactory, $marketProvider, $colorCodeProvider, $state, $globalFactory, $ionicLoading) {
      $ionicLoading.show();
      $scope.bar = {green: 0, orange: 0, red: 0, total: 1};
      $scope.currentSlide = 0;
      $scope.currentMarket = $cashDataFactory.getItem("currentMarket");
      $scope.colorCoding = $colorCodeProvider;

      function loadTop() {
        $webServicesFactory.get($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].topGetURL, {AnonymousToken: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].token}).then(
          function success(response) {
            $scope.topBuy = response.Stock.slice(0, 10);
            $scope.topSell = response.Stock.slice(10, 20);
            loadStockCount();
            loadTopF();
            loadTopV();
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          },
          function error(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          }
        );
      }
      function loadTopF() {
        $webServicesFactory.get($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].topFinURL, {AnonymousToken: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].token}).then(
          function success(response) {
            $scope.topFin = response.Stock.slice(0, 10);
            $scope.bottomFin = response.Stock.slice(10, 20);
            loadStockCount();
            loadTop();
            loadTopV();
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          },
          function error(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          }
        );
      }
      function loadTopV() {
        $webServicesFactory.get($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].topVinURL, {AnonymousToken: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].token}).then(
          function success(response) {
            $scope.topVin = response.Stock.slice(0, 10);
            $scope.bottomVin = response.Stock.slice(10, 20);
            loadStockCount();
            loadTop();
            loadTopF();
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          },
          function error(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          }
        );
      }
      function loadStockCount() {
        $webServicesFactory.get(
          $marketProvider[$scope.selectedMarket].queryURL+"/count",
          {AnonymousToken: $marketProvider[$scope.selectedMarket].token}
        ).then(
          function success(data) {
            data = data.Trade;
            console.info(data);
            $scope.bar.total = (data[0].BUY_total||0) + (data[0].HOLD_total||0) + (data[0].SELL_total||0);
            console.info($scope.bar.total);
            $scope.bar.green = 0;
            $scope.bar.orange = 0;
            $scope.bar.red = 0;

            $scope.bar.green = data[0].BUY_total;
            $scope.bar.orange = data[0].HOLD_total;
            $scope.bar.red = data[0].SELL_total;
            $scope.marketSentiment = data[0].Market_sentiment;


            $ionicLoading.hide();
          },
          function error(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
          }
        );
      }
      loadTop();
      loadTopF();
      loadTopV();




      $scope.openDetail = function (stock) {
        console.log(stock + " /hello");
        $globalFactory.stockDetail = {};
        console.info(stock);
        //if($scope.currentMarket == "kls")
        $globalFactory.stockDetail.stock = stock.Stock;
        $globalFactory.stockDetail.market = $scope.currentMarket;
        $state.go("app.screenerDetail");
      };


      $rootScope.$on("currentMarketChanged", function (e, market) {
        $scope.currentMarket = market;
        $ionicLoading.show();
        loadTop();
        loadTopV();
        loadTopF();
      });
    }
  ]
);
```

**css**

```
#screenerContent .slideTabWrapper{
  height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#screenerContent .slideTabWrapper .col{
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #16324f;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.one{
  border-bottom: solid #33cd5f 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.two{
  border-bottom: solid #ef473a 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.three{
  border-bottom: solid #33cd5f 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.four{
  border-bottom: solid #ffffff 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.five{
  border-bottom: solid #33cd5f 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.six{
  border-bottom: solid #ffffff 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.seven{
  border-bottom: solid #ffffff 3px;
}
.slideTabWrapper .col.selected{
  background-color: #102439;
}
```

what I required.

1. The pages and to slide correctly from 1 to 7
2. the tabs at the above will match with the pages when sliding.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple  ionic tab slider

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
 
    $scope.slideIndex = 0;

            // Called each time the slide changes
        $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
            $scope.slideIndex = index;
            console.log("slide Change");

            if ($scope.slideIndex == 0){
                console.log("slide 1");
            }

            else if ($scope.slideIndex == 1){
                console.log("slide 2");
            }

            else if ($scope.slideIndex == 2){
                console.log("slide 3");
            }

        };

        $scope.activeSlide = function (index) {
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
        };
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('https://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

.slide-tab{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00897B;

}

.slide-tab li{
    float: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide-tab a{
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00897B;
}
.current a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #00897B;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Slide Tab</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Slide Tab</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="slide-tab">
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 0 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(0)">Tab01</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 1 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(1)">Tab02</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 2 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(2)">Tab03</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 3 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(3)">Tab04</a>
          
          </li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 4 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(4)">Tab05</a></li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 5 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(5)">Tab06</a></li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 6 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(6)">Tab07</a></li>
 
        </ul> <!-- / tabs -->
        </div>
        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" active-slide="slideIndex" class="padding">
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 1</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 2</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 3</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 4</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 5</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 6</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 7</h3>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus pretium leo et dignissim. Nam aliquet sagittis turpis, eu dapibus ante suscipit nec. Cras vel dignissim nibh. Duis consectetur condimentum consequat. Nam ullamcorper congue nisi vel euismod. Nunc a tempus felis. Fusce lobortis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam id scelerisque felis. Integer posuere magna in porta finibus. Maecenas sit amet quam neque.

Duis gravida volutpat elit, in elementum neque cursus sit amet. Nullam euismod lectus dui, bibendum molestie sapien semper a. Ut sit amet nisi erat. Morbi et odio id est scelerisque porta. Curabitur ut gravida neque. Sed a fermentum ante, eget bibendum tellus. Mauris euismod mauris porttitor euismod cursus. In orci orci, condimentum sed mauris vitae, egestas iaculis erat. Phasellus eget suscipit nisl. Vivamus pulvinar, nibh vel hendrerit molestie, nunc dui sagittis justo, ac maximus turpis nunc eget ex. Vestibulum a risus mi. Proin elementum sem eget hendrerit lobortis. Etiam egestas aliquet nulla a hendrerit. Fusce convallis consequat consequat. Quisque id pellentesque nibh. Sed tempus neque ligula.</p>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

t

Comment: Thanks. How if I do not want to show the slide change log of slide change? I want to show my content, shall I replace it with function `loadTop`, `loadTopF` and `loadTopV`?

Comment: and replace with the content, I just add `loadTop`, can you show it, if you don't mine.

Comment: it still turn back to page 1 at page 6 and page 2 at page 7. I do not know why. ANy part of ionic control that?

Comment: may be you should try your code with different message in page 6 and page 7. I believe it will go back to page 1 and 2